# convert specific columns values to column_names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
index,col1,value
1,A,1
1,B,2
2,A,3
2,D,4
2,C,5
2,B,6
```

And I would like to convert this dataframe to this:

```
index,col1_A,col1_B,col1_C,col1_D
1,1,2,np.Nan,np.nan
2,3,4,5,6
```

The conversion is based on the `index` column value and for each unique `index` column, the column values from `col1` is converted to column name and its associated value is set to the corresponding value available in `value` columns.

Currently my solution contains looping by creating subset of df as temporary df based on each index and then starting looping there. I am wondering if there is already builtin solution available for it in pandas. please feel free to suggest.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='index', columns='col1', values='value')` or if needing the col prefixes `df.pivot(index='index', columns='col1', values='value').add_prefix('col1_')`

Comment: okay that was so simple. Thanks :)